# showing RunTimeError

Tags: python

while solving the same problem in python 3x on my machine, getting the correct output whereas during submission to hackerearth getting RunTimeError

```
for t in range(int(raw_input())):
i = list(map(int, raw_input().split()))
zom = []
vam = []
zc = 0
vc = 0
for x in i:
    if x%2 == 0:
        zom.append(x)
        zc += x
    else:
        vam.append(x)
        vc += x
zom.sort()
vam.sort()
zom.append(zc)
vam.append(vc)
print ' '.join(map(str, zom))+' '+' '.join(map(str, vam))
```

Comment: can you share your submission link

Comment: [link] (https://www.hackerearth.com/july-easy-15/algorithm/the-rise-of-the-weird-things-1/submission/2639121/)

Comment: you dont need any loop.Check my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is hackerearth  but try this one.

```
for t in range(int(raw_input())):
    i = list(map(int, raw_input().split()))
zom = []
vam = []
zc = 0
vc = 0
for x in i:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        zom.append(x)
        zc += x
    else:
        vam.append(x)
        vc += x
zom.sort()
vam.sort()
zom.append(zc)
vam.append(vc)
print ' '.join(map(str, zom)) + ' ' + ' '.join(map(str, vam))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=input()
i = map(int, raw_input().split())


zom = []
vam = []   
zc = 0 
vc = 0
for x in i:
    if x%2 == 0:
        zom.append(x)
        zc += x
    else:
        vam.append(x)
        vc += x
zom.sort()
vam.sort()
zom.append(zc)
vam.append(vc)
print ' '.join(map(str,zom))+' '+' '.join(map(str, vam))
```

You acutally dont need a loop.